# Finite second moment of the Wasserstein metric

Tags: probability-theory, metric-spaces

I want to show the following for $\mu$, $\nu$ $\in$ $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$:

> If $\int_\mathbb{R}|x|^2d\mu(x)<\infty$ and $\int_\mathbb{R}|x|^2d\nu(x)<\infty$ then 
>   $$W(\mu, \nu)= \left(\inf_{\eta\in \text{Adm}(\mu,\nu)}\int_\mathbb{RxR}|x-y|^2d\eta(x,y) \right)^{1/2}<\infty,$$ where $\textrm{Adm}(\mu, \nu)=\textrm{probability measures in}\ \mathbb{RxR} \textrm{ with marginal distributions}\ \mu \textrm{ and}\ \nu$.

$W$ is the Wasserstein metric.
I would be very thankful for solutions, advices or references!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The product measure $\eta := \mu \otimes \nu$ is in $\text{Adm}(\mu,\nu)$. Using that

$$|x-y|^2 \leq 2x^2 +  2 y^2$$

and the fact that $\mu$, $\nu$ are probability measures, we have by Tonelli's theorem

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} |x-y|^2 \, d\eta(x,y) \leq 2 \left( \int \nu(dy) \right) \left( \int x^2 \, \mu(dx) \right) + 2 \left( \int \mu(dx) \right) \left( \int y^2 \, \nu(dy) \right) < \infty.$$

Since the Wasserstein metric is defined as the infimum over all measures $\eta \in \text{Adm}(\mu,\nu)$, this proves $W(\mu,\nu)<\infty$.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Why do I need the two integrals,  which are 1 because of the probybility measures. May I understood Tonelli's theorem wrong..

Comment: @panda No, you are right; the integrals $\int \nu(dy)$ and $\int \mu(dx)$ both equal $1$.

Comment: I know, that they are 1, but why do I need them by applying Tonelli's theorem.

Comment: @panda Well, Tonelli's theorem tells you how to integrate with respect to the product measure: $$\int x^2 \, d\eta(x,y) = \int \int x^2 \, d\mu(x) \, d\nu(y) = \left( \int \, d\nu(y) \right) \left( \int x^2 \, d\mu(x) \right).$$

Comment: Oh thank you very much!! My fallacy..